# Data binding to a list inside a data bound object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm new to WPF and data binding so hopefully I can explain the problem I'm having with enough detail to get some help.

I have a list of objects that is data bound to a window. Let's say its a list of recipes. I have managed to get the application to display some details of each recipe in a list box, and some more details of the selected recipe in various text boxes. My problem is that I have a list of ingredients in each recipe that I want to display in another list box when the recipe is selected, but I can't work out how to get the data binding to work.

My data classes look something like:

```
public class Recipes : ObservableCollection<RecipeDetails>
{
}

public class RecipeDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients;
}

public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public string IngredientName { get; set; }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_recipes = new Recipes();
        // m_recipes initialisation
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = m_recipes;
    }

    private Recipes m_recipes;
}
```

And my data binding attempts (in XAML) look something like:

```
<Window x:Class="RecipeWindow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Recipe Window" Height="402.687" Width="532.674" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Margin="12,58.176,0,16.362" Name="recipeListBox" Width="209.07" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" Padding="5" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <StackPanel Margin="245.43,58.176,12,47.268" Name="detailsPanel">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="140" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Description,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="140" />
            <ListBox Name="ingredientListBox" Width="209.07" ItemsSource="{Binding Ingredients}" Height="118.17">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IngredientName}" Padding="5" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But when I try to run this code, the ingredient list box is always empty. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the way you declare and initialize Ingredients list, Make it as ObservableCollection and initialize the Ingredients collection only in the constructor as following

```
 public class RecipeDetails
{
    public RecipeDetails()
    {
        _ingredients = new ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient> _ingredients;

    private ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients
    {
        get { return _ingredients; }
    }
}
```

One more point to add to your approach, It is advisable to use [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) on this class so that TwoWay binding will be easily achievable here when you type something in the TextBox.

Comment: Worked like a charm, except I didn't need to initialise it in the constructor. Making it a public property such as:
    public ObservableCollection<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients
 { get; set; }
seems to be working fine.

Comment: Setter on ObservableCollection may give you update issue, if you change it later after DatBinding.